# Tools to track active application, or, how to get started making one

Tags: software-recommendation, monitoring, tools

I want to track screen activity, i.e. I want to record which window is active at what time, similar to the timeline feature of Toggl (https://toggl.com/track/features/). Does there exist some small tool that can run locally in the background that would record this information, as opposed to recording the whole screen?

[Screenshot of Timeline feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmiZE.png)

I have tried to search for things like "track active window", "application monitoring" and similar, but I mainly found monitoring tools for resource usage and screen recorders.

I would also be curious about resources about where how to get started to develop something like this myself and interfacing with Ubuntu internals.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to write some code? If so, you may want to go to the sub that helps with writing software.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The ideal case would be to find a simple tool that can just run locally in the background. If this does not exist I would be open to the idea of trying to develop something myself, but I would prefer not to.